# XSL I need to remove space

Tags: xslt-1.0

I need to remove the white space between `"|"`

Example:

```
|| 3.3 | A | 001 | 2017-03-03T16:57:51 | 01 *20001000000200001437 | Only free ||
```

I need this output:

```
||3.3|A|001|2017-03-03T16:57:51|01 *20001000000200001437|Only free||
```

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor will you be using? You could really use some extension functions here, if your processor supports them.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather awkward to do in XSLT 1.0.

Given the following input:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <item>|| 3.3 | A | 001 | 2017-03-03T16:57:51 | 01 *20001000000200001437 | Only free ||</item>
</root>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="remove-left-spaces">
            <xsl:call-template name="remove-spaces">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="' |'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable> 
        <xsl:call-template name="remove-spaces">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$remove-left-spaces"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="'| '"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="remove-spaces">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="remove-spaces">
                <xsl:with-param name="text">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $delimiter)"/>
                    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
                </xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>   
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <item>||3.3|A|001|2017-03-03T16:57:51|01 *20001000000200001437|Only free||</item>
</root>
```